How to embed a power bi paginated report when there's no dataset_id
I can go through normal power bi report by the example here https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master.
But when I try to embed a paginate report, the response of this endpoint https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/group_id/reports/report_id/ doesn't have a dataset_id like normal report. So I can't get the embed token for next step by endpoint https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken.
I noticed there's another body I can send, which is data source identities. But I can't find a endpoint to retrieve identityBlob. The response of this endpoint https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/group_id/reports/report_id/datasources only gives me datasources information.
So how to embed a powerbi paginate report without a dataset_id
